# Lumia 535 (OS 8.1 updated) is less touch sensitive

Tags: 8.1, display, touch, nokia-lumia-535

IS it true Lumia 535 (OS 8.1 updated) is less touch sensitive than other Lumia phones? The High/medium/Low sensitivity option also absent in this phone. Waiting for answers........

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Touch issue hasn't been fixed after the last update for Lumia 535 (*8.10.14226.359 / 02055.00000.14511.22002*).
Microsoft can't even properly respond to the new reports about that problem. All they can advice is to factory reset our phones - which obviously did nothing to bugged touch screen driver (or defective digitizer).

Also Lumia 535 has no touch sensivity options available.

Answer (score 4):

Well there's two parts to that answer:
First, there were some issues with the touchscreen on the Lumia 535 when it first came out, [but it's since been fixed.](http://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-rolling-out-lumia-535-software-update-fix-touchscreen-issues)

Second, the Lumia 535 does not have a high sensitive touchscreen like some of the higher end Lumia models meaning you can't use the phone using regular gloves. You shouldn't notice this during regular use though.